# Prevent div in flexbox from changing width with additional content

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox, angularjs-directive

Hi I have this web page where I have a list of angular.js directive elements that are strucured in a flexbox.

The directive elements look something like this:

```html
<div class="variable-input-container" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="var-input" tabindex="0">
    <span class="var-input-span" contenteditable="true"></span>
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" class="var-input-btn">[x]</button>
</div>
```

And they have this style:

```css
.variable-input-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
}
.var-input {
    flex-grow: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}
.var-input-span {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image: Directive]

Now my problem is that whenever this directive is used in a context where it doesn't have a fixed width, like a flexbox it is possible to just add to much content to the span element, so that it just gets bigger and bigger (and in the case of a flexbox structure it moves around all the other elements in the flexbox.).

[image: To big directive]

Unfotunatelly I can't just set a fixed width because I need the directive to be responsive for all kinds of structures and window sizes. Is there any other way I can fix this?